# Python 3.4 load data directory

Tags: python, python-3.4, loaddata

Hello to divine people with knowledge about Python.
I'm currently studying Python 3.4 and have encountered a problem.
About the load function, even when I used this function with the correct txtfile name an error appears.

```
results = []
with open('text.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        results.append(line.strip().split(','))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/CSSE1001/Assignments/SunMum/030415.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open('stations.txt') as inputfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
```

Looks like Python cannot find where the text.txt is..
Can someone please tell me how to set a directory of a function? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [os.chdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir). Alternatively, you could use [os.path.join(path, *paths)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to dynamically build the absolute path to hand over to the [open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function. It could also be that your `text.txt` file is not in the same directory as your `030415.py` file (`F:/CSSE1001/Assignments/SunMum`).

**Update:** There are several ways you can load an entire file.

- If you want to read all of a file as text, you can write `data = open('text.txt', 'rt').read()`
- If you want to get all of a file's binary data, you can use `data = open('text.txt', 'rb').read()`
- If you want the lines of a file, a simple way to get them would be with `lines = tuple(open('text.txt', 'rt'))`
- If you want the lines without the newlines, you could type `lines = open('text.txt', 'rt').read().split('\n')`
- If you want to process the lines efficiently while avoiding newlines, you could use `for line in (line.strip('\n') for line in open('text.txt', 'rt')):` to start a for loop.
- If you are working with [comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), you probably should look at the documentation for the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module available with Python.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I have another quesiton.
When I apply that code, I cannot obtain the whole content of the txt file. Is there a way to load the whole content of a txt file? Once again, Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Charlie Several code examples have been added for working with your `txt` file.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, and It seems to be loaded, but I can't have access to it. I know that I'm supposed to use a list, but I can't get a grip. Could you please provide a little tip/hint/guidance? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Charlie Could you perhaps paste the contents of the file to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and then describe what you are supposed to do with the file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kpPmKwTE

This contains a list of words that I'm trying to load to python. I have used the open functions and used print function after, which gave me this
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

It seems that it is loaded, but I'm struggling to find its contents.
Thank you for your concern again.

Comment: @Charlie Maybe this [code example](http://ideone.com/73Zqt7) will help you. The `words` variable should contain a list of words from your file. Make sure you set `READ_FROM_FILE` to `True` and place the program in the same directory as your `text.txt` file.